# Oracle monthly totals and grand total column and row

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I'm trying to generate a report using Oracle which looks like this:

[image]

I got the following tables:

```
REGION (IDRegion, Region_Name) 
SALES (IDSale, Sale_Date, Amount, IDSaleRegion)
Both tables are populated.
```

I cannot figure out how can I create that report by extracting each sum for the first 3 months and calculate the totals. 
I've only made this script but it's not so useful:

```
SELECT Region_Name as Region, 
COALESCE(NULL, NULL) AS "January", 
COALESCE(NULL, NULL)AS"February", 
COALESCE(NULL, NULL)AS"March", 
COALESCE(NULL, NULL)AS"GrandTotal"
FROM REGION r INNER JOIN SALES s ON r.IDRegion=s.IDSaleRegion
GROUP BY Region_Name;
```

EDIT: Problem solved except the TOTAL (below Region) which calculates the totals from each Month.
 Any ideas how to add this row?

Comment: No need to do `SELECT DISTINCT`, since the `GROUP BY` returns no duplicates.

Comment: What is the sense of `COALESCE(NULL, NULL)`?

Comment: I used the COALESCE only to generate the table header...

Comment: Do you have some data for testing? Also, what is your Oracle version? A few observations: With Oracle 11 or higher you can use the PIVOT operation. If performance is important, you shouldn't extract month from Sale_Date - you should have an index on that column, and write the filters in a way that allows the use of that index. (Using "extract" or any other function on it will prevent the use of the index.) Also, it is best to avoid column names in double-quotes, especially if the output from this query is or may be (in the future) used for further processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Conditional Aggregation`

```
select case grouping(Region_Name) when 1 then 'TOTAL' else Region_Name as "Region",
       sum(case when extract(month from Sale_Date) = 1 then Amount else 0 end) AS "January",
       sum(case when extract(month from Sale_Date) = 2 then Amount else 0 end) AS "February",
       sum(case when extract(month from Sale_Date) = 3 then Amount else 0 end) AS "March",
       sum(Amount) AS"GrandTotal"
From yourtable
Where extract(month from Sale_Date) <= 3
Group by Rollup (Region_Name);
```

Comment: It's working well! But how can I add second Total (below Regions) and calculate the GrandTotal?

Comment: @Mr.Gigi - I edited the solution to answer your remaining question. Please read about "group by rollup" (Google is your friend).

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
SELECT Region_Name as Region, 
sum(decode(extract(month from Sale_Date), 1, amount)) AS "January", 
sum(decode(extract(month from Sale_Date), 2, amount)) AS"February", 
sum(decode(extract(month from Sale_Date), 3, amount)) AS"March", 
sum(case when extract(month from Sale_Date)<4 then amount end) AS"GrandTotal"
FROM REGION r INNER JOIN SALES s ON r.IDRegion=s.IDSaleRegion
GROUP BY Region_Name;
```